# Jsp view page is not rendered in Spring boot. How to solve it?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to make an ajax request that sends a value to my spring boot. However, once I incorporate the ajax call and it successfully passes the value to java it does not view the `jsp` page. I believe the issue is from the method itself, but I am not entirely sure. Again I have the values being passed, but whenever I use `ModelAndView` or `Model` it seems to not change the page accordingly.

**JSP:**

```
 <script>
        var chaptersTest = ${ chapters };
        var totalChapters = chaptersTest.length;
        var codeBlock;

        for (var i = 0; i < totalChapters; i++) {

            codeBlock =


                '<div class="col-md-4">' +

                ' <a class="chapter_link" data-link="' + chaptersTest[i] + '" style="text-decoration: none; color: white"><div class="box warning">' +

                '  <h3>' + chaptersTest[i] + '</h3>' +

                '  </div></a></div>';

            $("#chapterArea").append(codeBlock);
        }


        //clicked links

        $('.chapter_link').click(function () {
            console.log("YoUR fUNCtION IS cLICKED");
            doSomething();
        });



        function doSomething() {
            var search2 = {
                "chapter": "riley"
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/ajax",
                data: JSON.stringify(search2),
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log("It somewhat worked");
                }

            });

        }



    </script>
```

**Java:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String sectionView(@RequestBody BEntity benny, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String temp = benny.getChapter();
        ModelAndView secView = new ModelAndView();

        try {
            secView.setViewName("viewsections.jsp");
            //It is not sending the jsp to change the page

        } catch (Exception e) {
            secView.setViewName("error.jsp");

        }


        System.out.println("Test 1");
        return secView;
    }
```

**Object:**

```
public class BEntity {

    private String search; 
    private String chapter;
    private String section; 

    public String getSection() {
        return section; 
    }


    public String getChapter() {
        return chapter; 
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "This was searched: " + search;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller,remove `@ResponseBody` annotation and change the return type to `ModelAndView`. Change `dataType` to `html` in your ajax code.

If you have not configured view properly then, in your `application.properties` set the prefix and suffix as:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

**spring.mvc.view.prefix** is the path of the folder where your jsp files reside.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView sectionView(@RequestBody BEntity benny, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String temp = benny.getChapter();
    ModelAndView secView = new ModelAndView();
    try {
        secView.setViewName("viewsections");
        //It is not sending the jsp to change the page
    } catch (Exception e) {
        secView.setViewName("error");
    }
    System.out.println("Test 1");
    return secView;
}
```

Comment: No, we did it the way you specified but we still can't get the page to view. It only shows the```System.out.println()```

Comment: have you configured your view properly? Like, setting the prefix and suffix for view.

Comment: Gautum No, even when I try the way you suggested it still does not render it.

Comment: Let me edit my answer. I will add the properties file as well.

Comment: Gautum Ok but I am still confronted with the same issue.

Comment: Have a look. Give it a try.

Comment: So I tried the way you said and it still doesn't work. I gives me the error of 404. ``` /views/view.jsp```

Comment: @kane_004 please see the edited code. Change the dataType to "html" in your ajax code.